# By having WordPress in a subfolder does it mean more script executions?

Tags: scripts

By having WordPress installed in a subfolder / directory does this mean WordPress will do more script executions then having WP installed at the root level?

**Edit:**
The root level index file has 645 563 number of executions while the sub directory index file has 34 739

Comment: The root level index file has 645 563 number of executions while the sub directory index file has 34 739.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by script executions and what tooling are you measuring it with?

Comment: Hi Tom, it was the stats from the web hosting company once I logged into the account. It just stated that the root level index file had  645 563 script executions while the index file inside the folder where WordPress was installed had only 34 739

Comment: Ooh, so you mean will a file be hit more if it's in a subfolder or in the root?

Comment: The WordPress website is running from a subfolder and in the root directory Ive updated the index.php to the following:
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . ‘/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php’ );

From here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

So when checking script executions  the root level index file has 645 563 while the sub directory index file has 34 739.

Comment: So no, Ethans answer is right, a script execution is a users browser hitting your site, moving where it hits doesn't change the fact that it's still 1 hit

Comment: Okay, it was just odd that the root file index.php would have so many more and I thought  they should both be the same as the root index.php is sending the url over to the subfolder index.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, **no**. Having your WordPress site installed in a sub-directly (ex: `http://some.site/wordpress`) does not mean it will do more script executions then having it installed at the root level.

Comment: Okay thanks, it was just odd that the root level index file had 645 563 number of executions while the sub directory index file had 34 739

Comment: @Bjarni You're gonna have to elaborate more on where you are seeing these scripts being executed. Despite the number change. Is everything working and displaying properly on your website?

Comment: yes site functions well though it was using up a lot of resources with the number of script executions for the index file at the root level.

The WP site is within a subfolder.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Comment: @Bjarni I don't believe that the amount of scripts being executed correlates to where your WordPress is located in this instance. Isn't having less scripts executing a good thing? Since this should essentially speed up your website's load time?

Comment: Okay it was just odd when compared the number of executions for the index file, one at the root level and the other in the subfolder

Comment: @Bjarni That looks like it could be a few variables that would require some more investigation on your end. I don't want to dive into that as this would stray this question to be off-topic. Since I've answered your question. Please up-vote and click the green checkmark next to my answer to indicate your question has been resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44459/discussion-between-ethan-jinks-osullivan-and-bjarni).